# Get product API details using runQuery (3DCART Advanced API)

Tags: php, database, soap

I'm trying to get [product](https://apirest.3dcart.com/Help/Api/GET-3dCartWebAPI-v1-Products-catalogid_limit_offset_countonly_sku_name_costfrom_costto_pricefrom_priceto_stockfrom_stockto_hide_freeshipping_onsale_nontax_notforsale_giftcertificate_homespecial_categoryspecial_nonsearchable_selfship_rewarddisable_lastupdatestart_lastupdateend) API details from the database using PHP.

```
<?php

class Data {
  private $db;
  public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new soapclient('http://api.3dcart.com/cart_advanced.asmx?WSDL',array('trace'=>1,'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1));
  }

  public function query($sql){
    $param = array(
      'storeUrl'=>"[URL]",
      'userKey'=>"[KEY]",
      'sqlStatement'=>$sql
    );
    $result = $this->db->runQuery($param);
    $match = $result->runQueryResult->any;
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($match);
    return $sxe->runQueryRecord;
  }
}

$db = new Data();
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE catalogid = 1");
var_dump($query);

?>
```

After running this program, I got this

```
<Error xmlns="">Error trying to get data from the store. Technical description: First request failed.This feature is disabled in demo mode. --- request params: storeURL=XXXXXXXXXXXX.3dcart.net, Method=runQuery, UserKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, UserIp=49.207.181.148, CallbackUrl=, sqlStatement=SELECT+*+FROM+product+WHERE+catalogid+%3d+1</Error>object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (0) {
}
```

Really I don't know that how to get product list using PHP. If anyone knows please suggest me how to get product list.

Answer (score 0):

The api you are using is in Demo mode, the error message tells you that the feature is switched off: "This feature is disabled in demo mode".

Find a way to get out of the Demo mode, probably contacting the support of 3dcart.com is a good starting point. I checked out their website and didn't find the reason why it is in demo mode.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Let me check their support team.